# Unable to pass data to fragment through Bundle

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm learning android fundamentals and I came across this problem while creating my first app. I have an activity which passes on data to a fragment. The `OnCreate` method of the activity has a block like this:

```
    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        DetailActivityFragment detailFrag = DetailActivityFragment.newInstance(movieId);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content,detailFrag).commit();
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
```

At the fragment (activity_detail) if I perform `getParameters()`, I receive `null`. By playing around, I found that if I remove `setContentView` method from the snippet above, the fragment shows up with the data. Any ideas as to why that was a problem? Thanks!

Edit: Here is my static newInstance method in the fragment

```
public static DetailActivityFragment newInstance(String id) {
    DetailActivityFragment fragment = new DetailActivityFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, id);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

Here's my fragment from the layout activity_detail:

```
<fragment android:name="app.appone.DetailActivityFragment"
android:id="@+id/fragment_detail"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: please call  setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail); above declaration of fragment

Comment: That's what I had thought the first time. That doesn't work

Comment: It would help to see the code for your `newInstance()` method, just to ensure `setArguments()` is being called on your new fragment correctly.

Comment: probably you forget to set arguments to your new fragment which you create DetailActivityFragment.newInstance

Comment: added my `newInstance()` method in the question

Comment: Your `newInstance()` method looks ok. I would personally create my own constant rather than use `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT`. Is it possible that it is the `String` argument that is `null`? How to you retrieve the data?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I'm creating the bundle which happens in the newInstance, a static method which returns the fragment after setting the arguments

Comment: @PPartisan No I double checked. The String `id` is never null before the arguments are set. It all seems to work if I just remove `setCotentView(..)`

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I'm following one of the recommended conventions. This way the data will be retained even if the fragment is re-created.

Comment: Ahh...your edit shows the problem. You're using a static fragment, but creating it dynamically! Remove the `<fragment>` element in your `xml` and replace it with something like a `FrameLayout` to hold the Fragment instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your latest edit shows you are using a static fragment in your `layout xml`, but creating it dynamically. A static fragment is created in your `xml` file:

```
<fragment android:name="app.appone.DetailActivityFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_detail"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Whereas a dynamic fragment is generated in your code with `FragmentManager`. It makes sense that calling `setContentView()` would cause a conflict, as the fragment you are creating with `FragmentManager` is being replaced by the fragment you are defining in your `xml` file. The one in your `xml`, unlike your dynamic fragment, has no arguments, which is why it's returning null.

As you use `android.R.id.content`, you can remove this static fragment from your `xml` completely. Replace it with an empty layout, such as `FrameLayout`, and set an `id` attribute. Then, when using `FragmentManager`, replace `android.R.id.content` for this `id`.

For example:

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frag_container" />
```

And in your `Activity` file:

```
DetailActivityFragment frag = (DetailActivityFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_container);
if (frag == null) {
    frag = DetailActivityFragment.newInstance(id);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beingTransaction()
        .add(R.id.frag_container, frag)
        .commit();
}
```

Comment: Excellent catch! I had completely overlooked Framelayout. I just tested with the changes and works perfectly. It also gave me the excuse to read more about FrameLayouts. Thanks!

Comment: @shark1608 You're welcome! FWIW, I'd recommend looking into the difference between static and dynamic fragments as well. I (and I believe most people) only ever use dynamic fragments because they are much more flexible, which could be why this solution might not be so obvious.

Comment: @shark1608 I'm not sure what you mean. Where are you trying to use `findViewbyId()` and for what purpose?

Comment: More or less what I posted :)

Comment: My suggestion was to get rid of the <fragment> in the layout file and use a placeholder instead. Therefore I do not need the findById method :)

Comment: @ThomasR. Yes your answer was similar to what PPartisan suggested. I only accepted his answer because he also answered my original question about why setContentView was causing a problem. I upvoted your answer and definitely give credit to you as well!

Comment: That's all fine for me :)

Answer (score 5):

You have to pass the data to your fragment.

Create a static method on your fragment for instance creation. It should look like this:

```
public static newInstance(Object param) {
  DetailActivityFragment yourFragment = new DetailActivityFragment();
  Bundle args = new Bundle();
  args.put(key, value);
  yourFragment.setArguments(args);
  return yourFragment;
}
```

And in your onCreate method of the fragment you can get that data using the method "getArguments();

Your activity code is ok. But I would prefer using "replace" instead of "add" method.

Comment: I have a static `newInstance` method which sets the arguments. Have a look at my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your edit. I think you are using the wrong id for fragment replacement.

As in a previous comment you should first set the content view. Your layout file should have a placeholder view, e.g. Framelayout. Give your layout an id and reference this id in your replacement code.

Your "R.layout.activity_detail" should have a layout snippet like this:

```
<FrameLayout id="+@id/my_detail_frag"/>
```

And your activity code should look like this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.my_detail_frag,detailFrag).commit();
```

Comment: That did not work either. Shouldn't `android.R.id.content` work with a fragment as well?

Comment: This id is the root view. I don't think that you should use it. Can you post your layout file? Are you getting the arguments in the fragments onCreate method? Is the onCreate method called?

Comment: Post everything you changed so far.

Comment: Not sure why you got a downvote. I've posted the fragment from the layout. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

This answer will do the trick for you:

[Best practice for instantiating a new Android Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment)

You should use setArguments() and getArguments() to pass the Bundle into the Fragment.

Good luck!

Comment: I have done exactly that. I've created the `newInstance` method in my fragment where I performed `setArguments()` . The `getArguments()` was done performed inside the OnCreate of the fragment

Comment: Hi,
You wrote that you perform getParameters ('the fragment (activity_detail) if I perform getParameters()')

Can you paste the code from inside the onCreate?